# What am I doing wrong in this solid of revolution problem?

Tags: calculus, volume

I have to calculate the volume of the solid of revolution that comes out after rotating the curves $y=\sqrt{x-1}$, $x=5$, $y=0$ around the axis $x=5$. What I did was: $$V=\int_{0}^{2}\pi(5-(y^2+1))^2dy=\frac{496\pi}{15}$$ The answer should be $\dfrac{256\pi}{15}$

Comment: TBH you just have to check your work and you should get the right answer. The expression you are starting with is correct.  Without knowing what you did it's impossible to say why you got the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After translating picture such that $x=5$ becomes $y$-axis, you get area bounded by $y=\sqrt{x+4}$, $x=0$, $y=0$. Now we express $x=y^2-4$, and the result is $\int_0^2\pi(y^2-4)^2dy$.